# Using Contains to Check for Object

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim manager_list As New List(Of ThirteenWeekSummary)

        For Each period In payroll_period_list
            With m_command.Parameters
                .Add("@PayrollPeriodID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = period
            End With

            'Get all the managers for this period
            m_connection.Open()
            m_command.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Dim rs As SqlDataReader = m_command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

            While rs.Read()
                Dim place_holder As New ThirteenWeekSummary
                place_holder.ReportingTo = rs.Item("ID")
                place_holder.FirstName = rs.Item("FirstName")
                place_holder.LastName = rs.Item("LastName")
                place_holder.Utilization.Add(period, 0)
                If Not manager_list.Contains(place_holder) Then
                     manager_list.add(place_holder)

                End If
            End While
            m_connection.Close()
```

I have a structure called "ThirteenWeekSummary."  It contains an integer for "ReportingTo" a first and last name for a given person, and I have a dictionary for Utilization.  I am using SQL to get all the records for a given week, write down the information into a structure, and then move to the next.  I'm using an arraylist called manager_list to keep track of who I already have.

I'm doing this for multiple weeks, because the list of managers each week could be different.  My thing is, if I already have a ThirteenWeek summary for Bob Jones, I don't want to create another one for him.  Does contains work for this?

Comment: `place_holder` was created as a ***new*** object just a few lines earlier so it wont be found in the list.  What you want to do is search objects in the list which have those properties.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Right!  So I have to use a for loop to iterate through all the objects in manager_list first?

Comment: Filter the manager list based on the properties you have: `manager_list.Contains(Function(s) s.ReportingTo = rs.Item("ID"))`.

Comment: You could create the object if the id isn't in the list.

Comment: You could also use a HashSet(Of whatever_type_id_is) to keep track of which IDs you've already processed.  HashSet.Contains will be faster than List.Contains if the list gets large.